# TextDecoder iso-8859-1: Fatal javascript OOM in Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit

Tags: javascript, deno

I'm workiing with very large CSV files (85Mo). After opening the file with `Deno.readFile`, I decode it with `new TextDecoder("iso-8859-1").decode(rawData);` and get the following error:

*note: I do not get this error with utf-8*

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[17822:0x5400000000] 27318 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1399.4 (1401.5) -> 1399.3 (1403.2) MB, 3173.1 / 0.0 ms (+ 0.1 ms in 431 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 3424 ms) (average mu = 0.191, current mu = 0.[17822:0x5400000000] 30483 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1399.8 (1401.7) -> 1399.5 (1402.5) MB, 3164.5 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.100, current mu = 0.000) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed

<--- JS stacktrace --->

#
# Fatal javascript OOM in Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit
#
[1] 17822 illegal hardware instruction
```

Deno Version: 1.2.2

Mac OS: 10.14.6

RAM: 16 Gb

## Question

What am I doing wrong when decoding my file with `iso-8859-1` encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that [this is a bug](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/7081).

> Seems like a bug in TextDecoder implementation in https://github.com/denoland/deno/blob/master/op_crates/web/08_text_encoding.js

To temporarily bypass the issue run deno with the following v8 flag:

```
--v8-flags=--max-old-space-size=8192
```